# Генерация перестановок в лексикографическом порядке от 1 до n.C++

Tags: c++, комбинаторика

Данная программа выдает неверные данные при N=5 и более.Сдается мне что есть проблемы в сортировке. Работает по следующему алгоритму:

1.Необходимо просмотреть текущую перестановку справа налево и при этом следить за тем, чтобы каждый следующий элемент перестановки был не более чем предыдущий . Как только данное соотношение будет нарушено необходимо остановиться и отметить текущее число.

2.Снова просмотреть пройденный путь справа налево пока не дойдем до первого числа, которое больше чем отмеченное на предыдущем шаге.

3.Поменять местами два полученных элемента.

4.Теперь в части массива, которая размещена справа от элемента,найденного в первом пункте, надо отсортировать все числа в порядке возрастания. То есть необходимо эту часть подпоследовательность просто перевернуть.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){


int n;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");


cout<<"Введите порядок числа: ";
cin>>n;
int a[n];
int k;//флажок сообщающий о возможности совершить перестановку
int o=1;//для нумерации перестановке в выводе


for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    a[i]=i+1;
}


cout<<"№"<<" "<<o<<" :";
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<a[i]<<" ";
}


    do  {
            int j=-1;// индекс для фиксации искомого номера элемента из пункта 1.
        k=0;
        for(int i=n-1;i>0;i--){

        if(a[i]>a[i-1]){
            k=1;
             j=i-1;
            break;
        } //зафиксировали

    }




        if(j!=-1){

        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        if(a[i]>a[j]){


            int temp=0;
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;
            cout<<"\n";
            break;

} //Нашли первый элемент,больший элемента из п.1 и поменяли местами

}

            int m=1;

            for(int i=j+1;i<n-1;i++){

                int gr=0;
                gr=a[i];
                a[i]=a[n-m];
                a[n-m]=gr;
                m++;
                } //сортируем часть массива,которая справа от элемента из п.1

            o++;
            cout<<"№"<<" "<<o<<" :";
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<a[i]<<" ";

                } //Вывели перестановку
        }





                            } while(k!=0);//пока можно совершить перестановку

    return 0;   }
```

Comment: К слову,эта программа работает корректно при n=2,3,4 но при n=5 выдает 112 вариантов из 120.

Comment: Так в чём проблема-то?

Comment: При n=5 число выводимых перестановок не 120.Извините,исправил вопрос.